# Issue with MPI_Sendrecv using 2D Matrix

Tags: c, mpi

As I know, `MPI_Sendrecv` requires two distinct buffers for send and receive. My following code sends (N/P) chunks of rows to `P-1` processors however it does not work and gives me a frozen screen. I tried to make sure everything is correct but I don't see where is the problem here (I omitted the variables declarations to make it short)

```
int **M, **FinalM, **M0;
M = malloc(N * sizeof (int *));
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    M[i] = malloc(N * sizeof (int));
}
FinalM = malloc(N * sizeof (int *));
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    FinalM[i] = malloc(n * sizeof (int));
}

M0 = malloc(N/P * sizeof (int *));
for (i = 0; i < N/P; i++) {
    M0[i] = malloc(N * sizeof (int));
}

c = N/P; // P is Number of Processors and N rows
if (rank == 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < P; i++) {
        k = i*c;
        k1 = (i + 1) * c;
        for (j = k; j < k1; j++) {
            MPI_Sendrecv(M[j], N, MPI_INT, i, TAG, FinalM[j], N, MPI_INT, i, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status[d]);
        }
    }
} else {

    for (i = 0; i < (N / P); i++) {
        MPI_Recv(M0[i], N, MPI_INT, 0, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }
}
```

Kindly, can someone give me a hint to solve this problem? 
Thank you.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs at https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Sendrecv.3.php#toc7:

> MPI_Sendrecv executes a blocking send and receive operation.

In your case, the master loop sends a portion of the matrix to the first worker and blocks, waiting for the worker to respond. There is no response, so it hangs forever. You need to either use just `MPI_Send` in the master loop, followed by another loop for `MPI_Recv`. The worker has to send something back using `MPI_Send`.

Comment: I see. I didn't notice that. Thanks for your explanation